# Google Cloud Storage Bucket creation

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I want to create a google bucket if it doesn't exist. Otherwise, I want to reuse the bucket name. How to do it?
Its equivalent of the unix command

> mkdir -p dir_name

I used the command but my shell script crashes when I run this next time.

> gsutil mb -l ASIA gs://my_bucket_name_blah_blah

Answer (score 15):

You could check for the existence of the bucket first. I think something like this would work:

```
gsutil ls -b gs://my_bucket_name_blah_blah || gsutil mb -l ASIA gs://my_bucket_name_blah_blah
```

Since the first command will return a 0 error code if the bucket already exists, the second command will only be executed if the bucket does not exist.

Note however that the first command will also return a non-zero exit code in the case of errors (transient error or permission denied). So you might need a more robust way of creating buckets.

Answer (score 2):

Following [BoHuang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33451883/google-cloud-storage-bucket-creation/72336655?noredirect=1#comment128342106_72336655:%7E:text=at%2010%3A21-,BoHuang,-364) answer I could came up with this:

```
# This function create a bucket
function create_bucket {

#PROJECT=$1
#BUCKET=$2
#REGION=$3
echo "Creating bucket [$2] in region [$3] for project [$1]"

if ! gsutil ls -p $1 gs://$2 &> /dev/null;
    then
        echo creating gs://$2 ... ;
        gsutil mb -p $1 -c regional -l $3 gs://$2;
        sleep 5;
    else
        echo "Bucket $2 already exists!"
        echo "Please revise the bucket and delete manually or rerun the code"
        exit 1
fi
```

}

Answer (score 1):

After six years ....

I found [this GitLab script](https://code.stanford.edu/xuwang/docker-gcsfuse/-/blob/351457a620e76ac1137791685015d24e1d04a18c/Makefile) can use as reference to solve this problem

The key part is

```
if ! gsutil ls -p ${GCP_PROJECT_ID} gs://${BUCKET} &> /dev/null; \
    then \
        echo creating gs://${BUCKET} ... ; \
        gsutil mb -p ${GCP_PROJECT_ID} -c regional -l ${GCP_REGION} gs://${BUCKET}; \
        sleep 10; \
    fi
```

That's a block of Makefile, but it's almost same as a shell script

Comment: I checked the above code block, it does not work

Comment: It does work nicely.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: I just followed your code and It worked for me. To be honest I just create a shell function to use it but the base is just your posted code :) Hope it helps.

What is exactly the error you found? Which version of gcloud SDK are you using? I'd like to replicate it

Comment: Nice to hear it works on your side. I have solved the problem with another method.

Answer (score 0):

You can relay on `gcloud` also

```
function ensure_gcp_bucket_exists {
  echo "Running "ensure_gcp_bucket_exists
  BUCKET_NAME="gs://test-bucket"
  if gcloud storage buckets describe "${BUCKET_NAME}" &> /dev/null ; then
     "GCP Bucket ${BUCKET_NAME} already exists"
  else
    echo "Creating GCP Bucket ${BUCKET_NAME}"
    gcloud storage buckets create "${BUCKET_NAME}" 
  fi
}
```